# Fridge keeps making noise

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator

I live in an apartment building. Every time my upstairs neighbor uses their water, it causes the back of my fridge to loudly shake. How can I stop this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: Is the fridge shaking, or just making noise?

Comment: I can see noise from water hammer in the wall, but to cause the fridge itself to make noise or shake is hard.  Are all four legs of the fridge tight on the floor?

Comment: Does your fridge have an icemaker or water dispenser?

Answer (score 6):

If your fridge has an ice maker or a cold water dispenser, the water supply for the fridge is a thin, flexible tube. This tube is probably reacting to the change in water pressure when the upstairs faucet is turned off, and I suspect the tube is slapping the back of your fridge due to the flexing motion of the tube.

Roll the fridge away from the wall slightly and find the spot where the tubing is slapping the back of the fridge. You can apply a piece of duct tape to keep the tube in contact with the fridge so it won't slap it and make noise, or you can tie or tape a random piece of foam rubber to the tubing or the back of the fridge at that spot to dampen the impact.

Answer (score 2):

There's a phenomenon called "water hammer" causing this. You can cure the nuisance by stiffening the flexible water supply line of your refrigerator. There's commonly a flimsy line taped to the back of the fridge, where you can tape it a bunch to solve the noise problem.

Water hammer is a bunch of pressure waves traveling around the plumbing system. The pressure can be 10 times the steady water pressure and can damage the supply lines, valves, etc., so a landlord has incentive to fix the problem. There are "water hammer arrestors" that put an air pocket into the system to absorb the shocks (water is effectively incompressible, but air obviously is not). Alternatively, faucet types that don't facilitate instantly stopping the flow of water (like a faucet with two rotating valves instead of a lever valve) will solve the problem. Or your neighbor could be a conscientious person and change his behavior by shutting the water off more slowly.